# Grails GORM: DuplicateKeyException on merge

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have two objects: `User` and `Resume`. Resume has a `User user` field.
In my code I first get a `user` object and do some changes on it. In case a `Resume.findByUser(user)` exists I get the resume and do some changes there as well.
If I call `user.save()` and `resume.save()` I get an exception saying that there is another reference to the same object in the session, so I began to use `merge()`.

When I call `user.merge()` the data is saved, but when I call `resume.merge()` I get this exception:
`org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.wizard.security.User#36]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.wizard.security.User#36]`

which I don't know what to do with. Looks like the problem is in the `resume.user` object which refers to the same one as the `user`.

I'll be grateful for help with this issue, thanks.

Comment: Not topical, but I just noticed that "Resume" is "user" backwards + "me".  Coincidence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since GORM is built on hibernate, when you call merge on **resume**, it will cascade down to field **user**.

When you call user.merge() and then resume.merge() within one transaction, by the time of calling resume.merge() your user field has newer version in DB than the one held on resume instance.

I suggest you call resume.user.refresh() or resume.refresh() before making changes and merging.

Comment: That was briliant! Thanks, you really helped me out.